# Flex 4's HSlider and TileLayout resizing problem

Tags: apache-flex, flex4

I have a simple application that consists of a HSlider and a list that contains a item renderer with a border container managed by a tile layout. For some reason when moving the slider to reduce the size of the item renderer it only reduce to a certain size and wont reduce any further. I use the same principle in flex 3 (with mx components it works fine). Any idea what I am doing wrong here?

This is the application mxml:

```
<s:Application xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009" 
           xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark" 
           xmlns:mx="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/mx" minWidth="955" minHeight="600">
<fx:Declarations>
    <!-- Place non-visual elements (e.g., services, value objects) here -->
</fx:Declarations>

<s:HSlider id="thumbSize" layoutDirection="ltr" snapInterval=".25" showDataTip="true" minimum=".8" maximum="2" value="2" liveDragging="true"/>

<s:List id="photosList"
        itemRenderer="ImageRender"
        horizontalCenter="0" verticalCenter="14" width="100%" height="90%" borderAlpha="0" selectionColor="white" allowMultipleSelection="true" rollOverColor="white">
    <s:layout>
        <s:TileLayout columnWidth="{80*thumbSize.value}" rowHeight="{79.5*thumbSize.value}" horizontalGap="0" useVirtualLayout="true"/>
    </s:layout>
    <s:dataProvider>
        <s:ArrayList>
            <fx:Object/>
            <fx:Object/>
            <fx:Object/>
            <fx:Object/>

        </s:ArrayList>
    </s:dataProvider>
</s:List>
</s:Application>
```

For the item renderer:

```
<s:ItemRenderer xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009" 
            xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark" 
            xmlns:mx="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/mx">
<fx:Declarations>
    <!-- Place non-visual elements (e.g., services, value objects) here -->
</fx:Declarations>
<s:BorderContainer  cornerRadius="19" top="0" bottom="0" left="0" right="0" borderAlpha="1" borderWeight="3" borderColor="0xc0c0c0"  backgroundColor="0xD3D3D3"  >
    <mx:Image id="img" top="5" bottom="20" right="5" left="5" horizontalAlign="center" verticalAlign="middle" source="http://xmxsolutions.com/images/flex_logo.jpg"  maintainAspectRatio="true"/>
</s:BorderContainer>
</s:ItemRenderer>
```

This should work with any flex 4 application.

Thanks for any pointers anyone can give me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[BorderContainer](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/spark/components/BorderContainer.html) has a minimum size of 112 pixels wide by 112 pixels high according to the docs.

I suspect it may be possible to make them smaller by setting the [explicitMinWidth](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/mx/core/UIComponent.html#explicitMinWidth) and [explicitMinHeight](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/mx/core/UIComponent.html#explicitMinHeight) or the [measuredMinWidth](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/mx/core/UIComponent.html#measuredMinWidth) or [measuredMinHeight](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/mx/core/UIComponent.html#measuredMinHeight).  but I haven't tested either.  Possibly [minHeight](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/mx/core/UIComponent.html#minHeight) and [minWidth](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/mx/core/UIComponent.html#minWidth) may come into play.